# Run Discord bot inside Django

Tags: python, django, discord.py

I would like to have a discord bot that accesses a Django DB. An obvious solution is to have 2 separate scripts. I would like to know if there is a way to make the discord-bot part of the Django as an app or something else.

Comment: You want to make project in Django that will be Discord bot, am I right? Nothing like Django DB does not exist, Django is web framework. Please specify your question more. From information you've given it is not clear why you would have to use Django.

Comment: [tag:discord.py] is an asynchronous library, so any other libraries you use with it should be asynchronous, especially those that involve potentially long-running requests, like a database driver.

Comment: @Krystofee no I have a Django and a discord bot 2 separate things. The bot accesses data on the Django app. But I want to know if it's possible to integrate that on the Django project. I hope I was more clear

Answer (score 1):

You could run a discord bot in a separate thread, and also set attributes to each other. Similarly, you could run django in a different thread if you want, too.

````py
import threading

django_app = DjangoApp()  # However this works, I'm not familiar with Django
bot = discord.Bot()  # commands.Bot() for the discontinued discord.py

bot.django = django_app
django_app.discord_bot = bot

thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: bot.run(BOT_TOKEN))
thread.start()```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `discord.py` you can create a management command like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

description = """
My bot from an SO answer
"""

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", description=description, intents=intents)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs the discord bot"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        bot.run(settings.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

I have also created a library to make this even easier https://pypi.org/project/django-discord-py/ but it certainly not required.