# Is there a way I can run a Discord bot alongside Django?

Tags: django, discord.py

I've used Django to make the site and now I'd like to be able to use the bot to grab info from Discord to use. For example how many members are in a particular server or only letting a person through to a certain page if they're in the server. Is there a way I can run the bot alongside everything else, or an alternative solution? Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:** Thank you for the suggestions below, however I read over everything several times and I just couldn't make much sense of how it would work, or how I could apply it. I just went for the easiest solution which I explain below
**Edit 2:** Forgot to edit this post again, but a while ago when I was trying to fix this, I actually scrapped the solution I put below and instead used a get request to get the number of members, a much better solution.

**The solution I used (Read edit 2 before this):**
This is probably one of the "harder to do" solutions, but since I found that I'm capable of doing it I went with it. Inside the main Django app I made a Python file for running the bot and a json file in which the bot could save data to. Then from that json file, the views.py file could grab information. The only "problem" here is that may be hard for others to keep a bot running consistently with an operating system that they dedicate to specifically that. I am using a Raspberry Pi that I keep on all day to run the bot straight from the project directory (I was already using the Raspberry Pi to run various Python bots so this just adds another bot). I don't know if there're any ways of running it from something such as Heroku and being able to have access to the project files.

Comment: This question has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808519/run-discord-bot-inside-django

Comment: I'd suggest using something asynchronous, as mentioned by Patrick in the linked thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but for the next ones who have the same problem

You can use a django management command ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/ )
just create a .py file under your_project/your_app/management/commands/<your_command_name.py>

and wrap the bot like this

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.conf import settings

from .bot import DiscordBot


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Run a discord bot"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        bot = DiscordBot()
        bot.run(settings.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

When it's done you can run your bot using:

```
python manage.py <your_command_name>
```

Comment: But how would Django communicate with the Bot?

Comment: There are many ways:

1. inside the django app call the bot related code
2. runs bot somewhere else, calls APIs built with django